TypeError: ForwardRef._evaluate() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'recursive_guard' on Mac
I was developing my fastapi project in my windows PC and everything was working fine there, but I recently got a new macbook and installed the lastest python 3.13 version and everything is just giving error
When I try to run my fastapi server, its giving this error :-
(venv) venvlisa@Lisas-MacBook-Air src % uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload 

INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/src']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [67473] using WatchFiles
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/multiprocessing/process.py", line 313, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
    ~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/uvicorn/_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
    ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 61, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/asyncio/base_events.py", line 721, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 68, in serve
    config.load()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 473, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/importlib/__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1022, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/src/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    from fastapi import FastAPI
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/fastapi/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .applications import FastAPI as FastAPI
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 16, in <module>
    from fastapi import routing
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 24, in <module>
    from fastapi.dependencies.models import Dependant
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from fastapi.security.base import SecurityBase
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/fastapi/security/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .api_key import APIKeyCookie as APIKeyCookie
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/fastapi/security/api_key.py", line 3, in <module>
    from fastapi.openapi.models import APIKey, APIKeyIn
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/fastapi/openapi/models.py", line 107, in <module>
    class Schema(BaseModel):
    ...<86 lines>...
            extra: str = "allow"
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 286, in __new__
    cls.__try_update_forward_refs__()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 808, in __try_update_forward_refs__
    update_model_forward_refs(cls, cls.__fields__.values(), cls.__config__.json_encoders, localns, (NameError,))
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pydantic/typing.py", line 554, in update_model_forward_refs
    update_field_forward_refs(f, globalns=globalns, localns=localns)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pydantic/typing.py", line 520, in update_field_forward_refs
    field.type_ = evaluate_forwardref(field.type_, globalns, localns or None)
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lisa/Documents/Projects/phia-backend-python/venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pydantic/typing.py", line 66, in evaluate_forwardref
    return cast(Any, type_)._evaluate(globalns, localns, set())
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ForwardRef._evaluate() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'recursive_guard'

And here is my requirement.txt :-
anyio
asyncio
click==8.1.3
fastapi==0.95.1
fastapi-jwt-auth==0.5.0
h11==0.14.0
httptools
idna==3.4
numpy
opencv-python==4.7.0.72
opencv-stubs==0.0.7
pika==1.3.1
Pillow
pydantic==1.10.7
PyJWT==1.7.1
python-dotenv==1.0.0
PyYAML
sniffio==1.3.0
starlette==0.26.1
typing_extensions
uvicorn==0.22.0
watchfiles==0.19.0
websockets==11.0.3
httpx
asyncer
aiofiles
watchdog
boto3


FastAPI and many libraries are not yet fully compatible with Python 3.13. Use a stable version like 3.11.x.
Make sure to clear existing env and recreate new env and also check pydantic and fastapi compatible version for 3.11.x

Python 3.13 should work with Fastapi but you have it version pinned to a quite old release - same for pydantic.
Py 3.13 may not work with (very) old packages. Especially old fastapi with latest asyncio would conflict in my mind...
Consider using/trying more recent versions of (all?) packages.
